# ¿Cómo mostrar los elementos de un array en PHP7?

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente código, donde recibo y guardo 2 argumentos de mi función en un *array*, ahora, tengo una segunda función que se llama **mostrar()** donde solo quiero que se imprima cuantos elementos hay en mi *array* si declaro el foreach dentro de esta me da el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: NOMBRE_COMPLETO

pero si declaro el foreach dentro de la funcion **guardar** si imprime el resultado que quiero.

```
<?php

class Persona{

    public $nombre;
    public $apellido;

    public function guardar($nombre, $apellido){

        $NOMBRE_COMPLETO = array(
            "NOMBRE" => $nombre,
            "APELLIDO" => $apellido
        );
    }

    public function mostrar(){
        foreach($NOMBRE_COMPLETO as $lista){
            echo $lista;
        }
    }

}

$persona = new Persona();
$persona->guardar("nombreX", "apellidoX");
$persona->guardar("nombreY", "apellidoY");
$persona->mostrar();
```

?>

Comment: trata de declarar $NOMBRECOMPLETO arriba de la funcion guardar, asi como tienes $nombre y $apellido a ver que sale

Answer (score 2):

¿Dónde defines `$NOMBRE_COMPLETO`?

Tal y como tienes el código, es un problema de definición/ámbito de variables: como no la defines en ningún sitio,  `$NOMBRE_COMPLETO` es una variable local que se perderá al final de cada función y que no estará definida en el resto de funciones.

Por eso aunque le asignes un valor (en `guardar`), dicho valor no estará disponible en otra función donde la variable estará indefinida recibiendo el error que ves (en `mostrar`).

Una posible solución sería definir nombre_completo como propiedad de la clase, pero entonces debería asignarse de una manera algo diferente, con this->nombre_completo:

```
<?php

class Persona{

    public $nombre;
    public $apellido;
    public $NOMBRE_COMPLETO;

    public function guardar($nombre, $apellido){

        $this->NOMBRE_COMPLETO = array(
            "NOMBRE" => $nombre,
            "APELLIDO" => $apellido
        );
    }

    public function mostrar(){
        foreach($this->NOMBRE_COMPLETO as $lista){
            echo $lista;
        }
    }

}

$persona = new Persona();
$persona->guardar("nombreX", "apellidoX");
$persona->guardar("nombreY", "apellidoY");
$persona->mostrar();
```

Comment: Para aclarar en el `mostrar()` va a imprimir `nombreYapellidoY` esto debido a que la `$lista` en dicha función es posición 1 `NOMBRE` posición 2 `APELLIDO`. Para imprimir otra persona, hay que declarar diferentes `$personas` y el `mostrar()` se llamaría con cada una de las "`$personas`" instanciadas.